# .htaccess rewriterule for directory doesn't seem to work only for subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My website has main domain & subdomains which has htaccess rewrite issue,

my issue is, there is htaccess code under www.example.com,

```
RewriteBase / 
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^?]*).html$ content.php?pid=$1
```

When i create content page with url path www.example.com/test.html or www.example.com/folder/test.html it works absolutely fine.

But i have same code on my subdomain & the 'folder' url doesn't work. I mean subdomain.example.com/test.html works fine but subdomain.example.com/folder/test.html doesn't seem to work.

Thanks a lot in advance.. :) Please help...

Comment: You must know first how is defined VirtualDocumentRoot for subdomain in your vhosts config file.

Comment: `But i have same code on my subdomain` Please post it here.

Comment: yes anubhava, i already have that code in subdomain's htaccess code too.. but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you post subdomain's htaccess code here?

Comment: Hi anubhava, the code is same as above except the filename is different, RewriteBase / 
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^?]*).html$ subdomaincontent.php?pid=$1

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code in your subdomain .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdomain/

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ subdomaincontent.php?pid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Make sure there is no other `.htaccess` below `subdomain`.